# CMake SWIG generated files installing and creating jar

Tags: c++, c, cmake, java-native-interface, swig

I am having trouble doing two things and would appreciate any help:

### 1. Acquiring a list of the files generated by SWIG (the java files in this case).

I can access/change what the output directory is. But I need a list of the java files. The only way I see people do this is using some custom command after build time. I am hoping there is a more modern cmake approach.

I have attempted to use the property `SWIG_SUPPORT_FILES` but it is missing one of the java files for some reason.

### 2. Putting the shared library (javaExample target) into the jar.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
include(UseJava)

set_property(SOURCE java.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(javaExample
  TYPE SHARED
    LANGUAGE java
    SOURCES java.i)

set_property(TARGET javaExample PROPERTY SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TRUE)
target_include_directories(javaExample PRIVATE ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(javaExample PRIVATE api)

add_jar(SDK
  #Swig generated java files
)

install_jar(SDK .)
install(TARGETS javaExample) # Would like to put this into the jar
```

Comment: I think I used some globbing stuff in CMakeLists last time I needed this

Comment: file glob is executed on cmake configure step. Swig files will be generated during cmake build. So you cannot use file glob.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but this can be achieved using the `SWIG_SUPPORT_FILES` target property:

```
get_property(_java_files TARGET javaExample PROPERTY SWIG_SUPPORT_FILES)
add_jar(SDK
  SOURCES ${_java_files}
)
```

Generator expressions work as well in some cases for this (when generating wrappers for Python as the target language), but it seems `add_jar` does not yet support generator expressions at this moment.